# Is jdbc or ldap faster for basic read operations?

Tags: performance, jdbc, ldap

I have a set of user data which I am try to access.  Due to the way our company's employee data is set up, the information is available both through LDAP and through a table in our DB.

I was curious, for standard read operations which would generally be a higher performance query?

Comment: It depends on your implementation of LDAP and which DB you are using. Some LDAPs use SQL DB as a backend. You need to benchmark your specific software as well as expected data.

Comment: It isn't mission critical performance, but I would rather go with the optimal approach.  @Jonathon Taking a few minutes to throw the question out there seemed a wiser decision than burning an hour or two building out two solutions and testing them against each other

Answer (score 1):

LDAP supports Extremely fast Read operations. Directories are tuned for higher read performance because the nature of the data in the directory is more commonly read than written or updated.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC and LDAP are only protocols, they don't impact performance nearly as much as things like indexing, caching, disk speed, network latency, etc.